# Angular.js and PHP: Keeping login information when page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

A user can use the login.html form which uses a submit button which calls an angular post method and sends the username/email and password to login.php where a MySQL table is stored. The rest of the user's information are gathered from the table and stored in $_SESSION, the session is json-encoded and sent back to angular.js.

Angular AuthController

```
app.controller("AuthController", function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $window) {

$scope.ctlr = 'Auth';

$scope.ngPOSTLogin = function() {
    var data = {
        UserName: $scope.UserName,
        Password: $scope.Password
    }
    $http.post('server/auth/login.php', JSON.stringify(data))
        .then(function(result) {
            $rootScope.user = result.data;
            //$window.sessionStorage['$rootScope.user'] = JSON.stringify($rootScope.user);
        });
};
});
```

Now, if a user refreshes the page the $rootScope gets refreshed as well, meaning the login data is lost. using $window.sessionStorage saves the entire JSON object (with the password) which shows that it should probably be encrypted.
The question is simple, how can I retain the user's login information even if they reload the page. I don't want to use someone's github projects (such as ngStorage).
My entire project - 
https://github.com/AquaSolid/RAMA_Angular_PHP

### Edit

This is an example of what login.php returns

```
{"ID":"3","UserName":"TommyGun","FirstName":"Tommy","LastName":"Larson","Email":"tommy.larson@gmail.com","Logged":true}
```

The password is never returned, I made a mistake while writing the question, sorry..

Comment: try localstorage of the browser?

Comment: "The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year." - I don't think this is good for user information

Comment: try localStorage, but you may want to save an encrypted combination of the username and password, to be used as key to determine if the session is open, you could also set a "lifetime" for the login so the storage expires... The date could be encrypted with the username and password... why you need the password here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why store the password in the browser?  The app doesn't need it. The user doesn't need it. The server doesn't need it. It's just a security hole with no upside.

When the user logs in, don't send back all of the info in the DB record. Only send back what the app needs to function. The rest can remain in Session.

As for your question about refreshing. Session or Local storage is the way to go. On the server side, store a `last_seen` timestamp in `$_SESSION`. Refresh it every time the user makes a new request. If the user hasn't been seen for a while, it will not be refreshed. So all you have to do is check whether `$_SESSION['last_seen']` is within the last 20 minutes or whatever. If it's too far into the past, call `session_destroy()` and require a new login.

Comment: This is the information that login.php returns, I don't know why I said that.. I will edit my question, sorry ..{"ID":"3","UserName":"TommyGun","FirstName":"Tommy","LastName":"Larson","Email":"tommy.larson@gmail.com","Logged":true}

Comment: That's a relief ;-) The same concepts from my answer apply. Only send back what the app needs. For instance why send back `ID`, `UserName`, full name and `email`?  Is all that needed for the app to function?

Comment: Well, no, but I was thinking of making a profile for each user. I don't know, this is a practice project. :-)

Comment: Oh I see. For a profile page, it makes more sense. I'm not sure what your question is anymore then. If it's about how to persist the session across refreshes, I explained: use local or session storage, and keep a `last_seen` value in the server `$_SESSION`